# setTimeout or child_process.spawn?

Tags: node.js

I have a REST service in Node.js with one specific request running a bunch of DB commands and other file processing that could take 10-15 seconds to run. Since I didn't want to hold up my browser request thread, I wrote a separate .js script to do the needful, called the script using child_process.spawn() in my Node.js code and immediately returned OK back to the client. This works fine, but then so does calling the same script (as a local function) by just using a simple setTimeout.

```
router.post("/longRequest", function(req, res) {
          console.log("Started long request with id: " + req.body.id);
          var longRunningFunction = function() {
              // Usually runs a bunch of things that take time. 
              // Simulating a 10 sec delay for sample code.
              setTimeout(function() {
                  console.log("Done processing for 10 seconds")
              }, 10000);
          }
          // Below line used to be 
          // child_process.spawn('longRunningFunction.js'
          setTimeout(longRunningFunction, 0); 
          res.json({status: "OK"})
      })
```

So, this works for my purpose. But what's the downside ? I probably can't monitor the offline process easily as child_process.spawn which would give me a process id. But, does this cause problems in the long run ? Will it hold up Node.js processing if the 10 second processing increases to a lot more in the future ?

The actual longRunningFunction is something that reads an Excel file, parses it and does a bulk load using tedious to a MS SQL Server.

```
var XLSX    = require('xlsx');
var FileAPI = require('file-api'), File = FileAPI.File, FileList = FileAPI.FileList, FileReader = FileAPI.FileReader;
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var TYPES   = require('tedious').TYPES;
var importFile = function() {

  var file = new File(fileName); 

  if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        var data = evt.target.result;
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'}); 
        var ws = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]; 
        var headerNames = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json( ws, { header: 1 })[0];
        var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);

        var bulkLoad = connection.newBulkLoad(tableName, function (error, rowCount) {
          if (error) {
             console.log("bulk upload error: " + error); 
          } else {
              console.log('inserted %d rows', rowCount);
          }
          connection.close();

        });

        // setup your columns - always indicate whether the column is nullable
        Object.keys(columnsAndDataTypes).forEach(function(columnName) {
            bulkLoad.addColumn(columnName, columnsAndDataTypes[columnName].dataType, { length: columnsAndDataTypes[columnName].len, nullable: true });
        })

        data.forEach(function(row) {
            var addRow = {}
            Object.keys(columnsAndDataTypes).forEach(function(columnName) {
                addRow[columnName] = row[columnName];
            })
            bulkLoad.addRow(addRow);
        })

        // execute
        connection.execBulkLoad(bulkLoad);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  } else {
      console.log("No file!!");
  }
};
```

Comment: If your database calls are asynchronous (which they should be), then there's really no reason to put them behind a `setTimeout()` or in another process.  You can just send the client response immediately and continue on with the async database calls.  Since they're async, they aren't costing the actual nodejs thread much at all in the way of cycles.  99.99% of the work is being done in your database process.

Comment: The question is about how do I make them async ? I was using child_process.spawn() to make them async, but it seems like setTimeout() works fine for that. So which one is better, and why ?

Comment: If you want advice on how to make your database calls async, then you need to show us your database code and describe what database you're using.  That's where the issue is.  `setTimeout()` does not make anything async.  It just postpones when the code runs to a future time.  The way the code is written both in your Javascript and in how the underlying operations are implemented in native code determine whether something is actually async or not.  We need to see THAT code in order to advise you further.  You appear to be slightly misguided about what is and isn't async.

Comment: OK, I made some changes to the question. It's not just about the DB commands. I am running a script that's doing a few other things also - parsing files, doing some computation and then uploading some results to the DB - all of which takes around 10-15 seconds. I understand setTimeout() is not making it async. All I really care about is not holding up the browser thread nor stalling the Node.js event loop.

Comment: As an example, if you have a loop that takes 10 seconds to run and it blocks the entire node.js thread for 10 seconds, then putting that on a `setTimeout()` just moves that 10 seconds of blocking from right now until whenever the `setTimeout()` is scheduled for. It's still blocking for 10 seconds, it's still not asynchronous and it's still bad for node.js, even if you start it at some later time. On the other hand, if you have actual async database operations, even if there are a lot of them and takes 10 seconds to complete, that doesn't take more than a handful of ms from the node.js thread.

Comment: Of everything else you describe, only parsing and computations actually take much node.js time.  Reading files, uploading should all be asynchronous which means they are done outside of the node.js thread.  I'm still not sure you actually are stalling the event loop in any way.  If you are, then `setTimeout()` does not help you at all.  That will just stall the event loop a little bit later from now instead of right now.

Comment: To fix an event loop stall (if you actually have one), you have to move CPU consuming operations to another process and that is typically done either with clustering or by using worker/child processes or by farming work out to another server process.  `setTimeout()` will not help you in the least with event loop stalls.  That will just change when the event loop is stalled.  You'd get the best help from us if you showed us the actual "time consuming" code.  Then we'd know what the best recommendation would actually be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the information. Maybe I am completely misinformed about how to go about this. Here's my core function (added to the question) that I'm trying to make sure doesn't stall the event loop. By that I mean, I don't want Node.js to wait till this function is complete before it accepts other connections.

Comment: What evidence do you have that you have an event loop blocking problem?

Comment: Can you include in your question NPM reference links to the modules you're using here that aren't part of the standard node.js library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, this works for my purpose. But what's the downside ?

If you actually have a long running task capable of blocking the event loop, then putting it on a `setTimeout()` is not stopping it from blocking the event loop at all.  That's the downside.  It's just moving the event loop blocking from right now until the next tick of the event loop.  The event loop will be blocked the same amount of time either way.

If you just did `res.json({status: "OK"})` before running your code, you'd get the exact same result.

---

If your long running code (which you describe as file and database operations) is actually blocking the event loop and it is properly written using async I/O operations, then the only way to stop blocking the event loop is to move that CPU-consuming work out of the node.js thread.

That is typically done by clustering, moving the work to worker processes or moving the work to some other server.  You have to have this work done by another process or another server in order to get it out of the way of the event loop.  A `setTimeout()` by itself won't accomplish that.

`child_process.spawn()` will accomplish that.  So, if you have an actual event loop blocking problem to solve and the I/O is already as async optimized as possible, then moving it to a worker process is a typical node.js solution.  You can communicate with that child process in a number of ways, but one possibility would be via `stdin` and `stdout`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. As for your last comment - I have no evidence. That's why this is more of an exploratory question (against Stackoverflow rules probably). Will this cause a problem if the long running code starts taking 1-2 minutes ? I tried making 60 parallel calls to my service at the moment and it still worked as expected. I can't seem to cause any delay in my server, and that's what scares me (that I'm missing something)

Comment: @AbhijitDixit - This is what node.js is really good at.  If all I/O is truly asynchronous, then the single node.js thread can serve a lot of requests without delay because I/O is non-blocking.  Anytime the node.js code is waiting for a response form some file or DB or networking operation, the node.js thread is 100% free to be working on other requests.  I personally would not go moving things to other processes until you have some evidence that there is actually a problem to solve and until you've proven that other, simpler code improvements can not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this. I will remove the setTimeout() and just do the res.json() before doing anything else. I will continue to monitor my server to see if any eventual problems arise.